# SQL : Insert if Not Exist

Tags: c#, sql-server

### Duvida:

Fiz um formulário em **C#** que faz conexão com o banco
Queria saber como posso incluir nessa query o *if not exits @param1*
Para não ocorrer duplicidades.

### Link do Código de referência:

[MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

### Base do meu código:

```
public void InsertDataToDb()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].
        ConnectionString;
    var records = GetRecords();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) " +
                " VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", DbType.String);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", DbType.String);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", DbType.String);

        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = item.param1;
            cmd.Parameters[1].Value = item.param2;
            cmd.Parameters[2].Value = item.param3;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um `WHERE` ao seu `insert` fazendo essa checagem, como [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446794/4551469):

```
...
new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) " +
    "VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3) " +
    "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE @param1 <> param1)");
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Na sua pergunta, você pôs uma referência a uma resposta para MySQL, mas o código está para SQL Server.

Caso você esteja procurando algo para MySQL, você pode usar o `INSERT... SELECT`, como está na mesma referência que você disponibilizou,

```
INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @param1, @param2, @param3
    FROM TableName
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE param1 = @param1)
)
```